# React Native ReferenceError: Can't find variable: True

Tags: variables, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Keep getting error that

```js
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: True
```

but everything seems good to me can you please help me spot the problem. This is also my first React Native project.

code below:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Dimensions,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  Image,
  Button,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import TacoTruck from "./tti.png";
import AntDesign from "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign";
import categoriesData from "./assets/data/categoriesData";
import Feather from "react-native-vector-icons/Feather";
import colors from "./assets/colors/colors";

const MenuPage = ({ navigation }) => {
  const renderCategoriesItem = (item) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        {/*Header*/}
        <View style={styles.headerWrapper}>
          <Image
            source={require("./assets/images/profile.png")}
            style={styles.profileImage}
          />
          <Feather
            name="menu"
            size={30}
            color={colors.vantaBlack}
            style={styles.menuIcon}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
          <Button
            title="Home"
            style={styles.buttonContainer}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Main")}
          ></Button>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>

      {/*Titles*/}
      <View style={styles.titlesWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.titlesSubtitle}>Food</Text>
        <Text style={styles.titlesTitle}>Delivery</Text>
      </View>

      {/*Search Bar*/}
      <View style={styles.searchBarWrapper}>
        <AntDesign name="search1" size={20} color={colors.vantaBlack} />
        <View style={styles.searchBar}>
          <Text styles={styles.searchText}>Search</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

      {/*Categories*/}
      <View style={styles.categoriesWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.categoriesTitle}>Categorles</Text>
        <View style={styles.categoriesListWrapper}>
          <FlatList
            data={categoriesData}
            renderItem={renderCategoriesItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            horizontal={true}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default MenuPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

u dont need to add '={true}', just

```
<FlatList
  data={categoriesData}
  renderItem={renderCategoriesItem}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  horizontal  
/>
```

Comment: I still keep getting error?

Comment: u should add some component in render item to tell, how the flatlist have to render items, maybe thats the issue

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I solved it inside my categoriesData file I had selected: True for some reason I took it off and it worked.